# Special clique in perfect graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

It is well known that in a perfect graph, there exists a clique which intersects all maximum  independent sets (stable set), as in [the proof of weak perfect graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph_theorem#Lov%C3%A1sz%27s_proof). So I want to know is the stronger statement true: In a perfect graph, there exists a clique which intersects all maximal independent sets.

(A maximum indepedent set is the largest indepedent set. A maximal independent set is an indepedent set which not contained in any larger independent set.)

Answer (score 6):

This stronger statement is not true. Consider $C_6$, which is bipartite and thus perfect. There are three maximal independent set of size two, but each clique intersects only two out of the three.